# Hide data receiving from card reader in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've got a card reader which is working as a keyboard (writes numbers and presses enter), and I need to provide received data to variable without showing them for user. How to do this in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: how is it connected this CR to your device? bluetooth?

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro Its connected via USB

Comment: Are you using an Android device?

Comment: I'm using UWP and Android device (in Xamarin Forms)